# How can we get list of all file systems(EFS) mounted to an EC2 instance using python boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-efs

I have used Boto3 to automate lot of things on AWS, but recently someone asked to list all filesystem of an EC2 instance. I am not able to find any direct method to get all mounted file systems(AWS EFS)to an EC2 instance.

I only have instance id. I have programatically access to AWS resources but no direct access to target instance. I have checked EC2 and EFS client but I surely be missing something so is asking here if anybody came across something similar want share his/her approach here.

I know we can run "df -h" to list all mount file systems but i cannot login to instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the programmatic access to the AWS resources, then you can easily solve your problem. What you can do is you can use the AWS System Manager Run Command (Send Command) API.

It allows you to run commands directly on the server and you can easily get the response of the command as an API response and by which you can get the response you want.

You can use the Run command to execute df -h on the instance and then you can filter the response in the python code or execute a single line command which will return you the list of names for the mount system.

Below are the links for AWS System Manager Run Command (Send Command): https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command

Comment: humm  "you can easily get the response of the command as an API response". Run cmd never return executed cmd output. it return executed cmd status. any ways I have achieved it by configuring a bucket to capture run cmd output.. waiting for 5 sec and then reading the file form s3 bucket with cmdid as filter.

Comment: It does return a command output but upto 25000 characters or so. The command output that you are receiving is actually the same output that you can see in the output section of the command. In the API, the key will 'StandardOutputContent'. Under this key, you will be able to see the output of your command.